# How properly write a condition in function that makes flow happy?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How properly write a condition in function makes flow happy?

My function should be able to handle 2 different data types.

link: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgZQJYFswBtoF4oBQUUA3gD5HEDUAdgIboQBcUcwiqNA5gDSVRU4AV0QQAcg2at2nXpTIBfAgVCRYCFEMiJi+SuX7UaqAMYBrCYxZsO3PsUXLV0eEij5XKDNmhl1SZC0kAG5lAgAzIRoTYFQAexooLghgTwAKIQ0WTwBKUkpUcIyNADp6RjySSgBIUWARRMykEuFRSwhKBSgILAR84ig6hqgmxDLTC0lOgi6oIA

```
// @flow

type UserSimple = {|
  +name: string,
  +sureName: string,
|};

type UserSuper = {|
  +nickName: string,
|};

type User = UserSimple | UserSuper;

function getUser(user: User) {
  if (user.name) {
    return user.sureName;
  }
  return user.nickName;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's impossible to do without unnecessary code.

See https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8079

For now you can add some extra checks and comments that this checks exist for flow only. For instance: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgZQJYFswBtoF4oBQUUA3gD5HEDUAdgIboQBcUcwiqNA5gDSVRU4AV0QQAcg2at2nXpTIBfAgVCRYCFEMiJi+SuX7UaqAMYBrCYxZsO3PsUXLV0eEij5XKDNmhl1SZC0kAG5lAgAzIRoTYFQAexooLghgTwAKIQ0WTwBKUkpUcIyNADp6RjySSgBIUWARRMykEuFRSwhKBSgILAQoQqg05zjwqCbEMtMLSXdcfAByG1l5yv46hrHS43N2zoIuqCA

Comment: Alex Savin thanks this is annoying, but exactly what I need.